# Resize thumb in seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar

I want to know, how to resize thumb in seek bar. I have done resizing the seek bar using minheight and maxheight. But the thumb remains in the same size. What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the thumb of an Android SeekBar to match the height of the SeekBar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648311/how-do-i-get-the-thumb-of-an-android-seekbar-to-match-the-height-of-the-seekbar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make seekbar thumb hitbox bigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005319/make-seekbar-thumb-hitbox-bigger)

Answer (score 3):

You can change size of thumb through adding style to SeekBar.
Here is the style:

```
<style name="CustomSeekbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">#1D5368</item>
    <item name="android:width">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:height">30dp</item>
</style>
```

Here is the Seekbar that you can use it in your layout:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/custom_seek_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/CustomSeekbar" />
```

Comment: This doesn't change the size of the thumb.

Comment: @ClassA yes it does

Comment: Thats work, thank bro !