# Make seekbar thumb hitbox bigger

Tags: android, seekbar

I made a customised seekbar that looks like this

[image]

the thing is that it is pretty hard to grab the slider. so what i wanted to to is to increase the hitbox of the thumb to make it easier. i tried a few things, but always messed up the seekbar look. any ideas how i could do that?

layout.xml

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/xxx"
    style="@style/SeekBar"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/pixel_130dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name_textview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="SeekBar">
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/pixel_20dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">@dimen/pixel_20dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/pixel_20dp</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/seek_bar_thumb</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/pixel_5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/pixel_5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/pixel_2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/pixel_2dp</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/seek_bar_progress_drawable</item>
</style>
```

seek_bar_thumb.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape>
            <size
                android:height="@dimen/pixel_16dp"
                android:width="@dimen/pixel_25dp" />

            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/slider_thumb"/>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, since there are apparently no smarter ways to do that, here is what I did now; only solution I found was to add a transparent area around the thumb image. I doubled its size and added the `thumbOffset` parameter to the `Seekbar`. That doesn't seem to be the best solution, but at least it works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The [TouchDelegate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html) class seems to be a good place to start.

See this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html) on how you can use it.

Comment: That's what i thought too at first. though for the TouchDelegate to work, i need to know the id of the slider thumb and i'm not sure if there even is one. I mean, i don't want to increase the hitbox for the whole slider, only for the slider thumb.