# Android - Change seekbar bar size

Tags: android, size, seekbar

I'm playing a bit with Android developing some sample applications and came across issue I can't get over with. I'd like to change width of "bar" of SeekBar view.

What I want could be better seen on screenshot provided

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XczAf.png

Could some please be so kind and help me out?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You simply need to provide a custom drawable for the thumb: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648311/how-do-i-get-the-thumb-of-an-android-seekbar-to-match-the-height-of-the-seekbar

Answer (score 1):

You can use thumb drawable for to change hight and and thumb image 
Use below line in seekbar xml file

```
android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb_draw"



<SeekBar
android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb_draw" />
```

//seekbar_thumb_draw.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <size
            android:height="40dp"
            android:width="40dp" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_thumb_image"/>
```

seekbar_thumb_image is image for thumb that u want

Answer (score 0):

Photshop the exact size that you want. Then save it in your drawables folder. Then reference it in the xml code for your seekbar.

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_contentt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seek_thumb_verywidebar" />
```

Comment: Is there a way to somehow size it dynamically.... [e.g. height=20px] ... should I resize the drawable