# Android create seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar

i have this layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="---------"
    android:background="@color/cast_expanded_controller_background_color">


    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sfondo_alto"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:id="@+id/backBtn"
        android:padding="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titolo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/backBtn"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/backBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Un due tre prova un due"
        android:textColor="@color/cast_expanded_controller_text_color"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="fonts/Quicksand_Bold"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/sfondo_alto"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="13dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icona_pausa"
        android:id="@+id/play_pausa" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="13dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ridimensiona_grande"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/ridimensionaImage" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22.5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ret_bianco"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ridimensionaImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/play_pausa"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/play_pausa" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and the result is this : 
[image]

How can i create a ImageView(seekpoint) that moves on the seekbar?
i also need a way to press the seekBar in a point and receive a percentage of the tap position

this is a remote video player
Sorry for bad english, i'm italian(:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your xml layout

```
             <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekBar_days"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:max="31"
                    android:maxHeight="3dp"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/thum" />
```

creat a drawable resource seekbar_progress.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
            android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
            android:centerY="0.75"
            android:endColor="#ff747674"
            android:angle="270"
            />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/primary"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

use this image for seekbar point

[image]

Comment: How can i set the thumb dimensions?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648311/how-do-i-get-the-thumb-of-an-android-seekbar-to-match-the-height-of-the-seekbar

Answer (score 0):

To get a Slider icon over SeekBar, add this to your XML and put the required drawable.

> android:thumb="@drawable/icon_slider_btn"

To get the Seekbar callbacks and track the progress, you will have to implement the relevent interface like this,

```
    public class YourActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

      //Do something with Progress,
      int progress = seekBar.getProgress();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SeekBar is just progress bar with draggable thumb .It is used to set value .Position of Thumb will decide the value .Best Example of SeekBar is volume set ,Brightness of screen etc .

```
              <SeekBar           
                    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:max="31"
                    android:maxHeight="3dp"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb" />
```

Implementation in Activity see here

http://www.techamongus.com/2017/03/android-create-seekbar-in-activity.html